# How to select DISTINCT results in an SQL JOIN query

Tags: sql, join, distinct

this is my query so please check it and tell me. in this query is execute successfully but distinct is not working:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(ticket_message.ticket_id),
  support_ticket.user_id,
  support_ticket.priority,
  support_ticket.subject,
  support_ticket.status,
  ticket_message.message
FROM
  support_ticket
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_message ON support_ticket.ticket_id = ticket_message.ticket_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN assign_ticket ON ticket_message.ticket_id = assign_ticket.ticket_id
```

Comment: DISTINCT operates on the whole result set, but I assume that you expect it to only operate on ticket_message.ticket_id.

Comment: yes. can u tell me how i use distinct on ticket_message.ticket_id

Comment: Don't select the other columns, then you will only get each  ticket_message.ticket_id once.

Comment: Distinct is ***not*** a function.

Comment: if i write "DISTINCT ticket_message.ticket_id" this only then also it not works.

Comment: u said that dont select other colmn but i also want data from those columns. then what i will do?

Comment: What database (and version) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The word `distinct` is a *modifier* to the keyword `SELECT`. So you need to think of it as `SELECT DISTINCT` and it ALWAYS operates across the entire row. It simply ignores the parentheses seen in the following:

```
select distinct(ticket_message.ticket_id)
```

because distinct is NOT a function.

So. What we appear to have is a support ticket with associated messages. There are usually multiple messages per support ticket, so I suspect what you want is more complex. For example you might want just the **most recent** message for each support ticket.

To achieve **most recent** we need a timestamp (or "datetime") column and we also need to know if your database supports "window functions". Let's assume you have a timestamp column called `message_at` and you database does support window functions, then this would reduce the number of rows:

```
SELECT 
    support_ticket.ticket_id
  , support_ticket.user_id
  , support_ticket.support_section
  , support_ticket.priority
  , support_ticket.subject
  , support_ticket.status
  , tm.file
  , tm.message
  , assign_ticket.section_id
  , assign_ticket.section_admin_id
FROM support_ticket
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            ticket_id
          , file
          , message
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY message_at DESC) AS row_num
        FROM ticket_message
    ) tm ON support_ticket.ticket_id = tm.ticket_id
        AND tm.row_num = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN assign_ticket ON tm.ticket_id = assign_ticket.ticket_id
```

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY message_at DESC)` assigns the number 1 to the **most recent** message, and later we ignore all rows that are > 1 thus removing unwanted repetition in the results.

So.

We really need to know much more about your actual data, the database (and version) you are using and your real needs. **It is almost certain that select distinct is NOT the right technique for what you are trying to achieve.**

I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ticket_message.ticket_id
FROM 
    support_ticket
LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_message ON 
    support_ticket.ticket_id = ticket_message.ticket_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN assign_ticket ON 
    ticket_message.ticket_id = assign_ticket.ticket_id
```

As soon as you add more columns to your query, DISTINCT also takes them into account as well.

Comment: sir, this works fine. but i also want other column from other table in single query how can i do this?

Comment: You can do it as in your question, but then again you may end up with more than one row in the result per ticket_id. Make sure you understand how DISTINCT works, it will return unique ROWS, so depending on your chosen columns you will get different results. Even if you would be able to have "distinct ticket_ids" and multiple other columns in your result, you would get arbitrary data and in your result row and miss other data that is associated to your ticket_id via database relations.